Saving contents of a listview as files
I want to make a notepad type application.
I'm using a ListView linked to an ArrayAdapter to display a String array where you can add or delete notes and it does just that.
To save the contents of the listView, I've tried SharedPreferences, or using the File class with various Java.IO methods such as inputStream to write files to the storage and they somewhat work. The only issue is that when I close the app from recents the listView is cleared and this is after I've granted read/write permissions.
I want the files written by the app and saved in the internal storage hopefully in the android/data folder.
HashSet<String> with SharedPreferences:
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("net.druidlabs.mindsync", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>(MainActivity.notes);
sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("notes", set).apply()

Where MainActivity.notes is the ArrayList
I was expecting to exit the app, both from backing out of the app and closing from recents, but only the backing out of the app works.
